# D3 force nodes not moving

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've been experimenting with d3 forceSimulation for a visualization I'm creating. I would like the circles to split up to preset heights when the button "sorted" at the bottom of the page is clicked. For a reason I cannot figure out nothing is moving. When I look at other examples, there is definitely movement but I don't see what I'm doing wrong. My `index.html`, `script.js` and `data.csv` files are hosted in this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/exavoltdesign/1dcbd5bf5d891a02a53b5a9ec95aa4ec).

I understand that it's a slow file because it's drawing close to 2000 circles. I'm going to make a canvas of it at a later stage. At the moment I'm focusing on movement.

http://jsfiddle.net/6hsgm5b7/

Comment: I deleted my answer as it covers only one of multiple issues with your code. I am afraid, I don't have the time to address the rest of these issues and the question might therefore even be a bit too broad for SO. There are, however, some really helpful and patient souls around who might pick up on this and talk you through the issues. For all those willing to help, I'll share the link to the runnable demo you set up for this: http://jsfiddle.net/6hsgm5b7/

Comment: Although you don't have the time, thanks anyway for taking the time to at least look at it. I got the base of the code from this bl.ocks page by Mike Bostock (https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6526445e2b44303eebf21da3b6627320) to which I added my own code and changed some other code.